# CSS editor component made in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, editor, components

I searched a lot on the web, but I did not find what I was looking for.

Does someone know a CSS editor made in JavaScript that can be used as a component ?

- It shall have an UI for programmers and for "normal" people.
- The more important part would be for not programmer, so it shall include easy way to modify CSS classes by selecting via a box its properties.
- Something like CKEditor, but for CSS files.
- It must be embeddable so it could be used as one of my editors.
- Repository is a plus.
- Free of use and charge.

Thank you guys for your advice.

Comment: I don't know of anything exactly, but I use a Chrome extension that has non-dev UI for changing styles. The [repo is on github](https://github.com/ankit/stylebot), perhaps they're using a plugin you could use too.

Comment: @DavidGilbertson Thank you for your suggestion, but it can't fit. The purpose is to modify existing CSS files by website administrators.

Comment: OK. Hey if you find something would you mind posting back here? I'd be interested to see what you end up with.

Comment: @DavidGilbertson For sure, but for now the only solution I see is to build it myself.